# parse html with XML::LibXML while not touching entities

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I'm using XML::LibXML to parse a chunk of html in order to change the title attribute of all the anchor elements.
The problem is that XML::LibXML tampers with un-encoded entites, and changes e.g '&' to '&amp;' in the url params in the href attributes.

How do i tell XML::LibXML to not try to encode or decode any of these entitites?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new(recover => 2);

my $html = '
<div>
    <span>this & that &amp; what?</span>
    <a title="link1" href="http://url.com/foo?a=1&b=2">Link1</a>
    <a title="link2" href="http://url.com/foo?a=1&b=2">Link2</a>
</div>';

my $doc = $parser->load_html(string => $html);

for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//*[@title]')) {
    $node->setAttribute('title', 'newtitle');
}

print $doc->toString(), "\n";

__END__
```

which produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>
    <span>this &amp; that &amp; what?</span>
    <a title="newtitle" href="http://url.com/foo?a=1&amp;b=2">Link1</a>
    <a title="newtitle" href="http://url.com/foo?a=1&amp;b=2">Link2</a>
</div></body></html>
```

As you'll see XML::LibXML has altered the urls, and also the text inside the span tag!

Comment: Well, basically, your input isn't valid XML. Perl has HTML parsers, maybe try one of them? (Though, its not valid HTML either, but HTML parsers are generally more forgiving)

Comment: @derobert, XML::LibXML's `load_html` is an HTML parser.

Comment: @derobert — It isn't valid HTML either.

Comment: So you want to manipulate HTML while preserving errors? I doubt you'll find any parser that will let you do that.

Comment: @Quentin, No, bare `&` is allowed in HTML, so he's not trying to preserve any error. (The spec says `&amp;` *should* be used, which is very different from saying it *must* be used.) Maybe you're thinking of XHTML.

Comment: @ikegami: It's not valid HTML because of the URLs. `&b` isn't a valid entity. I'm pretty sure this has been true since before XHTML. Also, keep in mind the HTML standard uses 'should' in weird ways; e.g., you only should use &lt; to avoid confusion with start of a tag (HTML4 §5.3.2). You'd need to check the SGML standard to be sure.

Comment: @derobert, That's not weird. You can do `& foo` and `< foo` but you should unconditionally use `&amp;` and `&lt;` to avoid making a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

> As you'll see XML::LibXML has altered the urls, and also the text inside the span tag!

You are mistaken. The URL did *not* change. Both the original HTML and the generated HTML produce the same URL (`http://url.com/foo?a=1&b=2`). The HTML is different, but the text displayed is not.

The same goes for the text in the span. Both the original HTML and the generated HTML produce the same URL (`this & that & what?`). The HTML is different, but the URL is not.

To my knowledge, there's no way to control what characters XML::LibXML's `toString` escapes. Apparently, it chooses to escape `&amp;` even when it's not technically required in HTML.

Any why not? There's no harm in having "`&`" escaped.

«`this & that &amp; what?`» and «`this &amp; that &amp; what?`» mean the same in HTML.

«`href="http://url.com/foo?a=1&amp;b=2"`» and «`href="http://url.com/foo?a=1&b=2"`» mean the same in HTML.

PS — If you want to produce HTML, you should be using `->toStringHTML()`, not `->toString()`. The latter produces XML.

Comment: Thanks. People usually don't encode url's they paste into href, src (script) attributes, etc. So the harm is that people will have to decode the encoded url parameters with their eyes while reading the source. And also that it makes it more difficult to do a diff of the html before and after the title update I'm ding... So there is actually some harm.

Comment: @user985995, Most HTML these days is XHTML, which requires that the "`&`" is encoded, so people have to get used to seeing `&amp;` anyway, so your argument doesn't really hold any water.